# Passing argument from GET to POST

Tags: spring, post, get, thymeleaf

I'm implementing simple web application using Spring and I'm stuck trying to implement resetting password mechanism. I decided to do this that way:
User get a link to his e-mail inbox that looks like this `site/reset_password?t=token`, then when he goes there (with GET) he sees form where he writes his new password. Sadly I came across some problems when user wants to submit his new password (with POST). In POST method I need this **token** from his link.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/reset_password", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String resetPassowrd(@RequestParam("t") String token, Model model) {
    try {
        ResetPasswordForm form = new ResetPasswordForm();
        form.setResetPasswordToken(token);
        model.addAttribute("resetPasswordForm", form);
        model.addAttribute("tokenStatus",TokenStatus.OK);
    } catch (WrongTokenException ex) {
        model.addAttribute("tokenStatus",TokenStatus.WRONG);
    }
    return "token/reset_password.html";
}
```

I tried to pass it in form object (the same object user fill up with his password), but in POST method this field is set to null.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/reset_password", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String resetPassowrd(@ModelAttribute @Validated ResetPasswordForm resetPasswordForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "token/reset_password.html";
    }
    userCompanyService.changePassword(resetPasswordForm);
    return "token/reset_password_success.html";
}
```

After finding out that field with token is null I tried adding another param to this method `@RequestParam(value = "t",required = false) String token`, sadly it isn't passed along request from GET to POST.
How should I make it work? I think the fact I use Thymeleaf alongside Spring is worth mentioning.

Comment: OK, so you pass the token in the model used by the reset_password.html page. What does this html page do with the token? It won't magically be submitted with the form contained in this page, unless you add it as a hidden input field of the form.

Comment: ResetPasswordForm has 3 fields : token,password,repeatedpassword. In `token/reset_password.html` I have a form that get from user password and repeatedpassword and then submits resetPasswordForm that's why I thought that token will stay in object since and don't do anything to him (I don't modify it).

Comment: You're completely misunderstanding how Spring, and the web in general, works. You send a request, containign parameters. Spring creates an object to hold these parameters, and then you generate HTML based on this object. And that's finished. Once the request has been handled, the object disappears. The next request is independant from the previous one. To have Spring remember stuff from one request to another, it would need to store that stuff in the session. But you really don't want to do that in general, and certainly not here. Use a hidden field with the token, and submit it with the form.

Comment: @JBNizet ok now i get it. I know that model is used to create a page from Thymeleaf's template. I just thought that since I provide an empty object (in my case not that empty) for a form I'm able to set some fields for it.  Anyways I used hidden field and now it works. Thank you very much for solution and some clarification how spring works.

Answer (score 0):

Adding  `<input type="hidden" th:field="*{resetPasswordToken}" />` solves the problem. With that Spring passes token argument to the POST method aswell.